# TV show about stories where host told "Imagine, Imagine a story!

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I can vaguely remember a TV show from my childhood about stories at bedtime. I really want to find out what it is called.

What I know:

- Aired around 7 to 8pm GMT on Cbeebies
- Created a story from a machine
- Machine created the story when the host told the viewers to "Imagine, imagine a story!"
- Each episode was about 30 mins long
- Discontinued (I think) around 2010
- Aired in the early to mid 2000s
- The host sat down in a high-backed chair and read the story out loud
- The host changed from a man to a woman half way through the series

That's all, folks!

Comment: Do you remember any of the actual stories?

Comment: @John No, it was 10 years ago Paulie_D it's a play on words designed to stay away from "Identify this movie" or "What's this movie"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show you are looking for is [Story Makers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_Makers)

> The programme starts as the library shuts in the evening. At the stroke of midnight, Jelly and Jackson (green and pink puppets who live in the library and hide in the daytime) come out and are joined by a guest presenter, one of the members of the Wordsworth family, who recites "The sun is down, the stars are bright, Story Makers come out at night". The Wordsworths together with Jelly and Jackson are the Story Makers.
>
> Objects found in the library are put into the top of the story machine (transformed from a desktop computer); Jelly, Jackson and the story maker then recite **"Imagine, imagine, imagine a story!"**; and the story machine produces a book containing a story based on the object. The story in the book is then "read out" (although this is replaced on screen by live action or an animation). The first story is usually a Play Book (live action with small children), and the remaining stories are animated (cartoons, stop-motion animation, or puppets). The characters in the stories are fairly consistent, including Sniff and Wag (two puppet dogs), Blue Cow (a cartoon cow, created by Blue-Zoo), Kevin the Spaceman (puppet), and so on. There is always a Blue Cow story and a Play Book - the third story varies between each episode.

Here is the song: